# How To Make Text Appear In Text Box, After Selecting Option From Combo Box In Visual Studio Windows Form C#

Tags: c#, windows, forms, visual-studio, combobox

I'm making a windows form, in it I've read some text files, I've got a combobox and what I want is when I select the option "Games" in the combobox is for the richtextbox2 to be filled with the text that is in the read file "game.txt".
And the same for the other options and text files. I've tried this if statement but I get an error stating that "I cannot convert string to bool".

```
     private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
                {

                }

                private void richTextBox2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
                {

                }

                private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
                {
                    //Fill combobox with names. 
                    comboBox1.Items.Add("Games");
                    comboBox1.Items.Add("Operating");
                    comboBox1.Items.Add("Information");
                        try
                    {
                   //read text from text files.
                        string game = File.ReadAllText(@"game.txt");
                        string operate = File.ReadAllText(@"operate.txt");
                        string information = File.ReadAllText(@"info.txt");

//if you select Games option in combobox, fill text box with text from read file "game.txt".
    if (comboBox1.Text = "Games")
                    {
                        richTextBox2.Text = game;
                    }
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        //display error if files not found. 
                        MessageBox.Show(" " + ex.Message); 
                    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In C# to check if one value is equal to another you need to use `==` operator.
So your `if` statement should look like:

```
if (comboBox1.Text == "Games")
```

**EDIT:**
Above will make your code compile. In order to make your program works as expected you need to move your `try/catch` block to the `SelectedChangedIndex` of your `ComboBox`, it can look like this:

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        //if you select Games option in combobox, fill text box with text from read file "game.txt".
        if (comboBox1.Text == "Games")
        {
            richTextBox2.Text = File.ReadAllText(@"game.txt");
        }
        else if (comboBox1.Text == "Operate")
        {
            richTextBox2.Text = File.ReadAllText(@"operate.txt");
        }
        else if (comboBox1.Text == "Information")
        {
            richTextBox2.Text = File.ReadAllText(@"info.txt");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //display error if files not found. 
        MessageBox.Show(" " + ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    //Fill the default comboBox item.
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        comboBox1.Items.Add("Games");
        comboBox1.Items.Add("Operating");
        comboBox1.Items.Add("Information");
    }

    public void Write(string category)
    {

        switch (category)
        {
            //if you select Games option in combobox, do work Games() method.
            case "Games": Games(); break;
            case "Operating": Operating(); break;
            case "Information": Information(); break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }

    //if you select Games , read file "game.txt" with together Read() method.
    public void Games()
    {
        richTextBox1.Text = Read("games");
    }

    //if you select Operating , read file "operating.txt" with together Read() method.
    public void Operating()
    {
        richTextBox1.Text = Read("operating");
    }

    //if you select Information , read file "information.txt" with together Read() method.
    public void Information()
    {
        richTextBox1.Text = Read("information");
    }

    //File reading process
    public string Read(string fileName)
    {
        string data = File.ReadAllText(Application.StartupPath + @"\" + fileName + ".txt");
        return data;
    }

    //Selected item process
    private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Write(comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString());
    }
```

Comment: Please also add an explanation of how you fixed the issue and what you are doing. Code alone might be confusing to some readers